# error when writing video to disk with openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to use openCV 4.2.0 to write a video to disk. I initialise it as follow.

```
cv::VideoWriter writer("image.avi", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 100, cv::Size(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT), false);

if (!writer.isOpened()) {
    throw std::system_error(10, std::generic_category(), "Cannot open video writer");
}

outputVideo = &writer;
```

The thing is that the first line always fails with error :

```
[ERROR:0] global C:\Users\mialland\Documents\Aryballe\Projects\opencv\opencv-4.2.0\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (415) cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:
OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\Users\mialland\Documents\Aryballe\Projects\opencv\opencv-4.2.0\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): image.avi in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

i don't understand as I followed several tutorial and nothing seems wrong.

Comment: One reason may be that you already have the image.avi file in the same directory, which is easy to check. Another reason is that the codec and the filename mismatch, that you can also check. And the last reason is that you don't have the needed codec in your system.

Comment: It's weird, because OpenCV is trying to open your "image.avi" with `CvCapture_Images` backend. Probably you don't have modules supporting MJPG. Try to run your code with `cv::utils::logging::setLogLevel(utils::logging::LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);` - at least it will print all available backends.